# How to make a page unsearchable in blog search?

Tags: pages

I want to make a specific page unsearchable. I don't want it's text to show up when i'm searching some text in the search box (on the sidebar on most themes).

Comment: I'm guessing i would have to edit The-Loop in some way, but how?

Comment: Please always add additional info to the question as edit instead of adding comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
function hide_from_search($qry) {
  if (is_search()) $qry->query_vars['post__not_in'][] = xXx;
  return $qry;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','hide_from_search');
```

The xXx is the ID number of the page to exclude. Just read it out of the URL on the backend. When you are editing the page you want to exclude look at the URL bar. You should see "post=xXx" in there.

Comment: cool, thanks. I ended up putting this in the beginning of The Loop: `if( get_post_type() != 'page' ) : ...` because i wanted to search only inside posts anyway and not inside pages

Answer (score -1):

Just to update, there's also a plugin called "Search Exclude" that does this exact thing without messing with the code.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-exclude/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/258199)